# Triggering scripts on system events in Unix / macOS

Tags: linux, macos, unix, javascript-automation

Is there a way to trigger scripts according to specific system events on Unix / Linux / macOS? Examples may be `beforeSleep`, `beforeLogout`, `afterVolumeChange` and the like.

I would like to write a script in javascript / jxa that gets executed just before the computer goes to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to accomplish your task atleast in Linux.

With `pm-utils` package you can write your own hooks and couple it with javascript.

Ex:
Please refer to this [How to trigger mount/umount before/after hibernation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/how-to-trigger-mount-umount-before-after-hibernation)

For volume management you need to check `udev` package.